# Separating an object from the background (2.8)

Tags: lighting

I am trying to make an 80s inspired flyer

So far I am really happy with the result. The only problem is that I can't seem to separate the metal writing (Laute Musik & Rosa) from the background. Since it is a shiny metal material it blurs into the background. Especially so when it is printed.
I have tried rim lighting to the best of my ability but it doesn't seem to help. If you look at the blend file you can see that as a last resort I built a black outline around the letters of the writing in the background. It helps a little but not enough.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/us4tbros6l2hi37/Vierj%C3%A4hriges18-LauteMusikLighting%20Kopie.blend?dl=0
[image]

Comment: I attached the blend file as a dropbox link. I have no idea if it works but I think it should. If it doesn't I'll try a different method of uploading it. As far as I understand it isn't possible to attach files to a post directly right?

Comment: Given that the background is as bright as the writing, there is very little contrast for the writing to stand out. Make the background a bit darker, or blur it a bit without affecting the writing by using different layers (or collections)